# IOS Swift How can I change 1 table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that has functionality on it to like and unlike a particular post. My issue is that if you like a post it shows correctly but if you scroll down and then up it forgets. How can I solve this?

```
@IBAction func voteAction(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let stream_id = streamsModel.streamID[sender.tag]
    let profile_id = streamsModel.Profile_ID[sender.tag]
    streamsModel.voteStatusv = streamsModel.VoteStatus[sender.tag]
    streamsModel.Likes = streamsModel.Votes[sender.tag]
    streamsModel.streamIDv = streamsModel.streamID[sender.tag]

    let cellT = getCellForView(view: sender)
    let indexPath = TableSource.indexPath(for: cellT!)

    if (indexPath != nil) {
        let cell = TableSource.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! HomeTVC
        if streamsModel.likeStatus == "0"   {
            // Liked
            cell.votes.setTitle(String(streamsModel.Likes+1), for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.likeImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "like2"), for:  .normal)
        } else {
            // Unliked
            cell.votes.setTitle(String(streamsModel.Likes-1), for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.likeImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "like"), for:  .normal)
        }
        // This snippet below causes an error
        //TableSource.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
    }
}
```

The code above simply checks if you liked something onClick if yes it adds +1 to the count and changes the image to like. If you unlike something then it does a -1 on the counter and changes the image to default. Again everything works correctly. My only issue is that if I scroll down and then back up it forgets that I liked something. The only way I have of fixing this is to call `tableView.reloadData()`. However, that is too much since I'm only updating 1 cell. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should maintain the liked flag as index and configure it during `cellForRowAt`

Comment: Where is this `voteAction` method? Is it in the view controller or the custom cell class? The proper solution is to update the data model, not the cell. Then tell the table view to reload the one row.

Comment: It is in the View Controller . Yes I plan on updating the data model just wanted to see if it was possible to do it in the action method . I will try to configure it in the cellForRowAt .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to also change value in your model array otherwise when you scroll tableview than you get old value.try this code

```
if (indexPath != nil) {
            let cell = TableSource.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! HomeTVC
            if streamsModel.likeStatus == "0"   {
                // Liked
                streamsModel.Likes = streamsModel.Votes[sender.tag] + 1
                cell.votes.setTitle(String(streamsModel.Likes+1), for: UIControlState.normal)
                cell.likeImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "like2"), for:  .normal)
            } else {
                // Unliked
                streamsModel.Likes = streamsModel.Votes[sender.tag] - 1
                cell.votes.setTitle(String(streamsModel.Likes-1), for: UIControlState.normal)
                cell.likeImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "like"), for:  .normal)
            }
            // This snippet below causes an error
            //TableSource.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
        }
```

Comment: Don't get the cell here. Just update the model then call `reloadRows(at` for the one index path. `cellForRow` will update the cell as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reloadRows(at:with:) method

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

NOTE: This methods accepts an array of IndexPaths, if you have to reload only a single cell, you need to pass that IndexPath in an array.

Also, the intermittent like/unlike issue is very common in reusable cells. You need to maintain that selection separately to appropriately show like only on chosen cells. If I get some more insight about what you are exactly doing, I may give you an exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in action of voteButton and then it reload particular cell.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```